# detecting object in server side in java

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I am writing a java program which is based on client-server using socket programming (one server-multi client) if I have two `ArrayList`s of *Class Type:  a* and *Class Type: b* in my server side I also have two`ArrayList`s of * Type: Thread* for each type *a* and *b* . Using a `while(true)` loop I'm `accept`ing the client Socket.

I want to how can I detect that the `Socket` named Client which filled is sent from a class type *a* or *b*? (because I need to add it to ArrayList s).

**CODE SAMPLE:**

```
public class Server {
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private ArrayList<Thread> driversServerThreads;
private ArrayList<Thread> passengerServerThread;
private ArrayList<Driver> drivers;
private ArrayList<Passenger> passengers;
private int clientCounter;

public Server() throws IOException {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2020);
    driversServerThreads= new ArrayList<>();
    passengerServerThread = new ArrayList<>();
    drivers = new ArrayList<>();
    passengers = new ArrayList<>();
    clientCounter = 0;
}

public void serverStart () throws IOException {
    System.out.println("System server is being loaded please be patient");
    System.out.println("There has been no connection yet you'll be informed when there's one");
    Socket client;
    while (true) {
        client= serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("New Client Is Connected!");
        //HOW CAN I KNOW WHICH KIND OF CLASS HAS SENT THE REQUEST?
    }
  }

}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: I think the question doesn't make much sense. Your server will happilly accept connections from clients written in C++ or Python or node.js or any other language which know nothing about your classes.

Comment: I know what you're saying but I need to apply different conditions for each different type of class and need to add each type to a different Thread